# Using internal pullup, pulldown resistors to find floating IOs

Tags: stm32, gpio, pullup, pulldown

I want to find at runtime if a GPIO is floating (nothing connected to it).

I assumed I'd find tons of answers on Google, but maybe I'm searching wrong.

My approach has been to:

- enable the internal pullup resistor and read the IO
- disable the pullup, enable the pulldown and read the IO again

If it reads high first and low second, the input is floating.

Since I've not seen a lot f discussion on this online, I'm wondering if I'm doing something unusual, or if there's a better way, or if this approach doesn't work in the general case and I simply lucked out in my application.

If this does work in the general case, I'm curious what happens with GPIOs that don't exist in a package. Presumably, if a particular IO line doesn't come out to a pin, there are no pullup or pulldown resistors for this line either. I'm curious particularly about what STM32 does in this case.

Comment: Your approach makes good sense, and should work. I'd say the reason that you're not seeing anything online is that it's a pretty rare need. The typical reason to check for a float is to look for fault conditions, and most stuff online is not designed for that level of robustness. As for the I/Os that don't come out to a pin, I don't know the specifics of the STM32, but I'd wager that the pull-ups are part of the silicon itself, so they'll still be there even if the I/O isn't bonded out to a physical pin.

Comment: This makes sense about a rare need. My original use case was for reading a three-position switch with one IO line instead of two. Right now, I'm trying to come up with a way of telling different generations of a board apart, and using this "floating" logic gives me 3^n instead of 2^n combinations out of the same number of pins. There are other ways, of course, like different voltage divider ratios on a single ADC pin. How long would you say the code should wait to let pullup/pulldown settle before reading the input register?

Comment: I would say just wait for 3 times the [RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant). R will be a pessimistic (high) estimate of the pull-up / pull down resistor's resistance, and C will be the pin capacitance, which should be in the datasheet, plus another few pF to account for the board. Probably will end up being really fast.

Comment: The highest possible  R value needed to toggle state can be selected and bus impedance measured by RC response curve can compute the tri-state R and Vref. right?   Using a fixed C and ADC sample rate to match resolution needed. I could not find any STM32 3s bus analog tests but lots of digital self-tests

Comment: @iter very bad and volatile approach. Not connected pin as third state is a very bad idea.

Comment: @P__J__ can you elaborate?

Comment: The [LTC6804](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/680412fc.pdf#page=29) BMS IC uses a very similar approach, but using an ADC instead of digital pins. Therefore, the idea can't be too far off :)

Comment: @Mr.Snrub: I ran the same test using a pin that exists in larger packages of the same chip but not in the the 32-pin one I'm using. The input value stays low even if I try to activate the pullup. It appears that at least some of the circuitry is missing from the die for these IOs. Toobad--I was hoping to use them as a way to tell one part number from another.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. I was presuming this pin was truly an I/O, i.e. could have an output enabled. But if the pin is an *input only*, then the most sensible thing to do with an unused input pin is to tie it to ground, regardless of whether or not it has pull-up/pull-down resistors.